# CSS animation repeating with jquery hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a problem with a repeating CSS animation that is executed by a jquery hover function. You can see an example of the problem in this **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/vXoZXy)**.

When you open the demo please hover over the first star and pan the mouse from left to right. As you can see the animation repeats itself causing a stutter. How can I fix this so that the animation only fire once per star, keeping the previous stars highlighted.

HTML

```
<div class="GvStarContainer">
  <!--Style 1 STARTED-->
  <div class="GvStarTmp">

    <div class="margi-star">
      <div class="rate-ex1-cnt">
        <div id="1" class="star star-one-1 rate-btn star-one"></div>
        <div id="2" class="star star-one-2 rate-btn star-one"></div>
        <div id="3" class="star star-one-3 rate-btn star-one"></div>
        <div id="4" class="star star-one-4 rate-btn star-one"></div>
        <div id="5" class="star star-one-5 rate-btn star-one"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--Style 1 FINISHED-->
  <!--Style 2 STARTED-->
  <div class="GvStarTmp">

    <div class="margi-star">
      <div class="rate-ex2-cnt">
        <div id="1" class="star star-two-1 rate-btn star-two"></div>
        <div id="2" class="star star-two-2 rate-btn star-two"></div>
        <div id="3" class="star star-two-3 rate-btn star-two"></div>
        <div id="4" class="star star-two-4 rate-btn star-two"></div>
        <div id="5" class="star star-two-5 rate-btn star-two"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--Style 2 FINISHED-->
  <!--Style 3 STARTED-->
  <div class="GvStarTmp">

    <div class="margi-star">
      <div class="rate-ex3-cnt">
        <div id="1" class="star star-tree-1 rate-btn star-tree"></div>
        <div id="2" class="star star-tree-2 rate-btn star-tree"></div>
        <div id="3" class="star star-tree-3 rate-btn star-tree"></div>
        <div id="4" class="star star-tree-4 rate-btn star-tree"></div>
        <div id="5" class="star star-tree-5 rate-btn star-tree"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--Style 3 FINISHED-->
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var prevStars = $(this).prevAll();
  var nextStars = $(this).nextAll();

  $(".star").hover(
    function() {
      var prevStars = $(this).prevAll();
      prevStars.addClass('rate-btn-hover');
    },
    function() {
      var prevStars = $(this).prevAll();
      prevStars.removeClass('rate-btn-hover');
    }
  );

  $("body").on("click", ".star", function() {
    var prevStars = $(this).prevAll().addBack();
    prevStars.addClass('rate-btn-active');
  });
});
```

Comment: You could add some timeouts before adding and removing the classes.

Answer (score 1):

You are applying the animation to both `:hover` selector and `.rate-btn-hover` class with this:

```
.rate-ex1-cnt .rate-btn:hover, .rate-ex1-cnt  .rate-btn-hover, .rate-ex1-cnt  .rate-btn-active{
    background: url(http://www.oobenn.com/GvStar/css/img/rate-btn1-hover.png) no-repeat;
    -webkit-animation-name: bounceIn;
    animation-name: bounceIn;
    -webkit-animation-duration: .75s;
    animation-duration: .75s
}
```

Instead apply the animation only to `:hover` selector

```
.rate-ex1-cnt .rate-btn:hover {
    background: url(http://www.oobenn.com/GvStar/css/img/rate-btn1-hover.png) no-repeat;
    -webkit-animation-name: bounceIn;
    animation-name: bounceIn;
    -webkit-animation-duration: .75s;
    animation-duration: .75s
}
```

and remove the animation properties from `.rate-btn-hover` class

```
.rate-ex1-cnt  .rate-btn-hover, .rate-ex1-cnt  .rate-btn-active{
    background: url(http://www.oobenn.com/GvStar/css/img/rate-btn1-hover.png) no-repeat;
}
```

See first star group in updated [**Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rMXGzv).

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that you are clearing the previous stars in the hover() 'handleOut' function. You want to retain those stars as filled, therefore you only want to clear 'next' stars, and then separately manage the cleanup of all stars as you exit the area containing the group of stars.

```
$(".star").hover(
    function() {
       $(this).prevAll().addClass('rate-btn-hover');
       $(this).addClass('rate-btn-hover');
    },
    function() {
       $(this).nextAll().removeClass('rate-btn-hover');
       $(this).removeClass('rate-btn-hover');
    }
);

$(".margi-star div:first-child").hover(
    function() {
    },
    function() {
       $(this).children().removeClass('rate-btn-hover');
    }
);
```

With this approach I am handling the start of the animation through script by setting the current controls class:

```
$(this).addClass('rate-btn-hover');
```

The difficulty with a pure css solution in your current code is that you are setting a background image in your **.rate-btn:hover** selector, but then the non hover state managed by **.rate-btn** has a different background image (empty star). This causes the filled star to be replaced with a blank star when **.rate-btn:hover** is no longer active.

As the css hover event is no longer required in my attempted fix, you can also remove the :hover selector from your css as follows:

```
.rate-ex1-cnt  .rate-btn-hover, .rate-ex1-cnt  .rate-btn-active{
    background: url(http://www.oobenn.com/GvStar/css/img/rate-btn1-hover.png) no-repeat;
    -webkit-animation-name: bounceIn;
    animation-name: bounceIn;
    -webkit-animation-duration: .75s;
    animation-duration: .75s
}
```

The full demo is here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VKorea